# how to read V Card file(contact number,name etc) in flutter without use string split

Tags: flutter, vcf-vcard

[image]

i try to read contacts number and name from this  V Card file.
i don't know,what is the proper any way to read .

i use string split method.
but any other proper way to read this, please suggest

( V Card file image show here)

Comment: `String.splitMapJoin` / `StringScanner` ? but why to make your life harder if you already have easy solution?

Comment: yes you are right,split string is good option. but i think may be another solution. that i don't know..
@ pskink

Comment: yes i use it already.but its so complex for separate and read all data.

Comment: what is complex?

Comment: example :- for Phone number get in TEL in work and home ,and same as address has two fields work and home. and same as other filed for iterate data.

Answer (score 3):

You can user VCard parser from  https://pub.dev/packages/vcard_parser 
add to pubspec

```
dependencies:
  vcard_parser: ^0.1.6
```

in code import

```
import 'package:vcard_parser/vcard_parser.dart';
```

Now

```
Map<String, Object> map = VcardParser(String VCardcontent).parse() ;
```

Comment: Thanks for response, but this library not define how they work.
@Dev

Comment: Its work,but not so exact for read all data .work same as Split method.i was use it
its get data like for email :-   EMAIL;TYPE=INTERNET: {name: INTERNET, value: demo@gmail.com},

Comment: bro this is the only available parser on pub as much as i know.

Comment: i agree with you.but i think may be these have another solution also..

Comment: Hey have you get the solution for this stuff because I also get in stuck to read vCard file in flutter